# Find index of any array using value in string array

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
a=[
    {x:1,y:1,i:"Piechart1"},
    {x:2,y:1,i:"Piechart2"},
    {x:3,y:1,i:"Piechart3"}
]

str=["Piechart1","Piechart3"];
```

I want get index by comparing array string.Output in above example should be [0,2]
Could you please let me know how to achieve in lodash ,javascript

Comment: enjoy, it maps each value in "str" to their indexes in "a" returns -1 if no index found u can strip these with filter after if you wish.
str.map((str) => a.findIndex((ele) => str === ele))

Comment: You right, I delete my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map()` to map the strings to their index, and `.findIndex` inside the `.map()` callback to locate the index of the object.

```js
var a = [{x:1,y:1,i:"Piechart1"},{x:2,y:1,i:"Piechart2"},{x:3,y:1,i:"Piechart3"}];

var str = ["Piechart1","Piechart3"];

var res = str.map(s => a.findIndex(o => o.i == s));

console.log(res);
```

You can chain `.filter(idx => idx != -1)` on the end if there's any chance of one of the strings not being in the main array.

Answer (score 0):

maps each value in str to their index in a.

```
str.map((str) => a.findIndex((ele) => str === ele.i))
```

Comment: got [-1,-1] ideally should be [0,1]

Comment: sorry for an array of objects comparison it should be...
str.map((str) => a.findIndex((ele) => str.i === ele))

Comment: If @GauthamShetty is going to mark this as the accepted answer, at least fix it so that it works like the correct answers. The code in your comment is also incorrect, so just copy and paste my answer if you need help. It's the one that says *"You're welcome"* below it, which was in response to the OP thanking me for posting a working solution, though the OP removed that show of appreciation.

Comment: As I said, go ahead and copy my answer so that the accepted answer is correct. Including your comments, this is your fourth time posting an incorrect solution. Don't know why @GauthamShetty chose it.

Comment: `str` is a string, so `str.i` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` method and `includes()` to check if element exists in another array.

```js
const a = [{"x":1,"y":1,"i":"Piechart1"},{"x":2,"y":1,"i":"Piechart2"},{"x":3,"y":1,"i":"Piechart3"}]
const str = ["Piechart1", "Piechart3"];

const result = a.reduce((r, {i}, ind) => {
  return str.includes(i) && r.push(ind), r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```